# Python- find substring and then replace all characters within it

Tags: python, regex

Let's say I have this string :

```
<div>Object</div><img src=#/><p> In order to be successful...</p>
```

I want to substitute every letter between `<` and `>` with a `#`.

So, after some operation, I want my string to look like:

```
<###>Object<####><##########><#> In order to be successful...<##>
```

Notice that every character between the two symbols were replaced with `#` ( including whitespace).

This is the closest I could get:

```
   r = re.sub('<.*?>', '<#>', string)
```

The problem with my code is that all characters between `<` and `>` are replaced by a single `#`, whereas I would like every individual character to be replaced by a `#`.

I tried a mixture of various back references, but to no avail. Could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: What's the expected output for `<div>>` ?

Comment: What's your expected output for this `<><>foo<>` input?

Comment: If it is simply empty, then they can remain empty... so it would remain the same

Comment: This appears to be more complex than I initially planned, if what I want to do is not solvable, I will select an answer below as they will suffice.

Comment: Yep, it's so hard to do with regex..

Comment: I'd appreciate if the down vote could be reversed, I think my initial question, disregarding the **Edit**, is legitimate. I simply didn't think before editing...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about...:

```
def hashes(mo):
    replacing = mo.group(1)
    return '<{}>'.format('#' * len(replacing))
```

and then

```
r = re.sub(r'<(.*?)>', hashes, string)
```

The ability to use a **function** as the second argument to `re.sub` gives you huge flexibility in building up your substitutions (and, as usual, a named `def` results in much more readable code than any cramped `lambda` -- you can use meaningful names, normal layouts, etc, etc).

Comment: Let's say I have `<div>>`, not all characters in between the two primary symbols will be replaced, I would have `<###>>`, could you kindly edit? I'll edit my question.

Comment: Your '<(.*?)>` matches only the `'<div>'` part in `'<div>>'`, so of course the extra '`>`' does not participate in the substitution.  Maybe you want `<([^<]*>`?  I'm only addressing the **substitution** part in the A so far.  I see you've edited the Q, let's see...

Comment: Yes, for the string I am currently using, you're initial answer works perfectly... probably shouldn't have added the **EDIT** part in my question, and just left it that. I realized afterwards how impossible what I wanted really is... in fact I think I'll unedit.

Answer (score 2):

The `re.sub` function can be called with a function as the replacement, rather than a new string. Each time the pattern is matched, the function will be called with a `match` object, just like you'd get using `re.search` or `re.finditer`.

So try this:

```
re.sub(r'<(.*?)>', lambda m: "<{}>".format("#" * len(m.group(1))), string)
```

Comment: The answer is good, but it doesn't replace everything in between the two symbols if, say, I have `<div>>`. I'll edit my question to include this.

Comment: Yes, well, that's one of the reasons why you [shouldn't parse HTML or XML with regular expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1405065).